# Go and namespaces: is it possible to achieve something similar to Python?

Tags: module, namespaces, go, package

I wonder if there is a way to use namespaces in the Go language in a similar way as Python does.

In Python if I have the following files containing functions:

```
/a.py
    def foo():
/b.py
    def bar():
```

I can access `foo` and `bar` in a third Python file as following:

```
import a
a1 = a.foo()
import b
b1 = b.bar()
```

I had some difficulties finding some documentation on namespaces with the Go language.
How are namespaces implemented in go? With `package` and `import`? Or is `import` dedicated to external libraries?

I think I understood that for each package there should be a dedicated directory. I wonder if this is absolutely mandatory, because it can become impractical whenever a high granularity of modules is the best way to engineer a certain idea. In other words, I would like to avoid using one directory per package (for internal use).

Comment: It basically works the same. If you import a package foo and foo exports some Bar you access it like `foo.Bar()`. I think the documentation on golang.org is pretty clear in this sens. What are you missing?

Comment: I think I understood that for each package there should be a dedicated directory. I wonder if this is absolutely mandatory, because it can become impractical whenever a high granularity of modules is the best way to engineer a certain idea

Comment: the current implementation *requires* that all source files for a package live in the same directory.

Comment: @JimB : what you say doesn't mean that *many* packages cannot live in the same directory. Moreover, I didn't say that I want to split a single package into several directories. What I wish would be avoiding using one directory per package (for internal use).

Comment: The converse is also true in this case. There is an enforced 1 package to 1 directory mapping in the toolchain.

Comment: Hmm, does this mean that if I want to use `package foobar` I *have to* create a subdirectory `foobar/` ?

Comment: Yes! What's so complicated about "one package per one directory"? It is dead simple, no "but", no "maybe" no "how about", just one package per one directory.

Comment: It's absolutely not complicated, it just smells like over-redundancy, especially if I want to have just one file per package. Isn't there really a much more lightweight concept of "namespace" in Go?

Comment: Again: No, there isn't. You may believe us. (Side note: One file per package might be a bad idea in some cases: Either your file will be ugly large or your package too small to be useful)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Go's equivalent to Python modules are packages.  Unlike Python modules that exist as a single file, a Go package is represented by a directory.  While a simple package might only include a single source file in the directory, larger packages can be split over multiple files.

So to take your Python example, you could create a file `$GOPATH/src/a/a.go` with the following contents:

```
package a

import "fmt"

func Foo() {
    fmt.Println("a.Foo")
}
```

In your main program, you can call the function like so:

```
package main

import "a"

func main() {
    a.Foo()
}
```

One thing to note is that only exported types and functions in `a` will be available externally.  That is, types and functions whose names begin with a capital letter (which is why I renamed `foo` to `Foo`).

If you don't want to set up a Go workspace, you can also use relative paths for your imports.  For instance, if you change the import in the main program to `import "./a"`, then the source code for the `a` package can be located at `a/a.go` relative to the main program.

Comment: It should be noted that relative import paths are heavily discouraged.

Comment: just curious, why are relative imports discouraged? not currently using them, but just curious thx

Comment: @AlexanderMills I guess workspace and especially URL based ones allow for more portable code as you can leave dependency management to `go get`.